# functions inheriting structure from the structure of the codomain

Tags: functional-analysis, logic, category-theory, homological-algebra

This question is kind of vague and I'm just asking for a reference. I have noticed the following 'behaviour' in many instances in mathematics.

Example 1.

> Let $ (M,+,*)$ and $(N,\hat{+},\hat{*}) $ be $R$-modules, then $\text{Hom}_R(M,N)$ is an abelian group and this is only due to the fact that $(N,\hat{*})$ is an abelian group.

Example 2.

> Let $(C_b(X), \|\cdot\|_\infty )$ be bounded linear functions (on some $X$-locally compact Hausdorff) then it is a Banach space. This is in a similar vein inherited from the completeness of $\mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$) into which we are mapping.

Is there a name for this kind of occurrence in mathematics, i.e., when functions (that are reasonably well-behaved w.r.t. the structure we are considering) between spaces of a similar kind inherit the structure from the codomain?

Usually, when things look similar in very different areas of mathematics, there is something categorial going on (or so I presume).
I also just might be overlooking something trivial, in that case a nudge in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: The closest thing that comes to mind is the internal $\mathrm{Hom}$: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+hom

Comment: This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list (otherwise it will be bumped up periodically). Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the problem. See [How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I only have a partial example, covering the algebraic examples. For these, let me start by noting that the pattern fails for instance for general groups: for groups $G$ and $H$, the set $\mathsf{Grp}(G,H)$ equipped with the binary operation $*$ defined by $(\alpha*\beta)(g)=\alpha(g)\beta(g)$ is *not* a group, as $\alpha*\beta$ is not a group homomorphism. The problems disappear when assuming that $H$ is abelian. In particular, we do not need $G$ to be abelian. So, noting this, a hopefully interesting way of looking at the algebraic examples, which also explains why it fails for groups, is as follows (unfortunately, I don't know how to connect it to the example of Banach spaces): let $\mathcal{T}$ be a category with finite products, and call it a *theory for placeholder objects*. For any other category $\mathcal{C}$ with finite products, a *placeholder object of $\mathcal{C}$* is a finite-product preserving functor $\mathcal{T}\to\mathcal{C}$, and the category of placeholder objects in $\mathcal{C}$ is the full subcategory $\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathcal{T},\mathcal{C})$ of $\mathrm{Fun}(\mathcal{T},\mathcal{C})$ on all finite-product preserving functors.

In the special case where $\mathcal{T}$ has an object $x$ for which any object of $\mathcal{T}$ is isomorphic to some finite product $x\times\ldots\times x$, the category $\mathcal{T}$ is called a *Lawvere theory*, and many algebraic structures can be described in terms of them, see e.g. [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory#examples). For instance, (commutative) monoids, (abelian) groups, sets and $R$-modules over a (commutative) ring $R$ are examples. This also explains why I called a general $\mathcal{T}$ as above a theory of placeholder objects, as ''placeholder'' is a placeholder for things like groups, monoids, etc. If $\mathcal{T}$ is a Lawvere theory and $A\colon\mathcal{T}\to\mathcal{C}$ is a finite-product preserving functor, we call $A(x)$ the *underlying object* of the placeholder object $A$.

**Observation.** Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a category with finite products. If $F\colon\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ is a finite-product preserving functor between categories admitting finite products, then $F$ induces a functor $F\circ -\colon \mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathcal{T},\mathcal{C})\to\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathcal{T},\mathcal{D})$.

In other words, if $F$ preserves finite products, it sends placeholder objects of $\mathcal{C}$ to placeholder objects of $\mathcal{D}$ by acting objectwise.

In particular, if $\mathcal{T}$ is a theory of placeholder objects, $c\in\mathcal{C}$ is any object in a category with finite products, and $A\colon \mathcal{T}\to\mathcal{C}$ is a placeholder object of $\mathcal{C}$, then the hom-sets $\mathcal{C}(c,A(-))\colon \mathcal{T}\to\mathsf{Set}$ form a placeholder object in sets. By definition, the placeholder structure on the latter is induced by the placeholder structure on $A$, so by the placeholder structure on the codomain.

This shows in one go that, for any set $c$ and any monoid/commutative monoid/group/abelian group/ring/commutative ring/$R$-module/... $A$, the hom-set $\mathsf{Set}(c,M)$ also admits the structure of a monoid/commutative monoid/group/abelian group/ring/commutative ring/$R$-module/..., induced by this structure on the codomain. This is about inducing a structure on the collection of all *set maps* $c\to M$. If $c$ itself has the same structure as $M$, it is not immediately clear (and generally false) that the collection of all homomorphisms $c\to M$ also admits this same structure.

If $\mathcal{T}$ is a theory of placeholder objects, it holds by the observation above that, if $M\colon\mathcal{T}\to\mathsf{Set}$ is a placeholder object in $\mathsf{Set}$ and $N\colon\mathcal{T}\to\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathcal{T},\mathsf{Set})$ a placeholder in the category of placeholder objects in $\mathsf{Set}$, the collection $\mathrm{Hom}(M,N(-))\colon\mathcal{T}\to\mathsf{Set}$ of placeholder homomorphisms between $M$ and $N(-)$ is a placeholder object in $\mathsf{Set}$. This for instance implies that $\mathsf{Grp}(G,H)$ is an abelian group if $H$ is, because an abelian group is also an abelian group object in groups.

**Assumption.** We assume $\mathcal{T}$ is such that the product functor $\mathcal{T}\times\mathcal{T}\to\mathcal{T}, (s,t)\mapsto s\times t$ induces (after currying) an equivalence $\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathcal{T},\mathsf{Set})\to\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathcal{T},\mathrm{Fun}^\times(\mathcal{T},\mathsf{Set}))$ of categories.

This assumption says that every placeholder object in $\mathsf{Set}$ can be canonically enhanced to a placeholder object in placeholder objects in $\mathsf{Set}$. For instance, any abelian group is an abelian group object in abelian groups in a canonical way, and a similar statement holds for commutative monoids (this is an instance of Eckmann-Hilton). The assumption is false if $\mathcal{T}$ is the Lawvere theory of *all* groups.

**Observation.** If $\mathcal{T}$ is a Lawvere theory that satisfies the assumption above, and if $M,N\colon\mathcal{T}\to\mathsf{Set}$ are two placeholder objects in $\mathsf{Set}$, then the set of placeholder homomorphisms $\mathrm{Hom}(M,N)$ admits a canonical enhancement to a placeholder object in $\mathsf{Set}$ (for which $\mathrm{Hom}(M,N)$ is the underlying object), induced by the placeholder structure on the codomain.

The reason I assume $\mathcal{T}$ is a Lawvere theory above is that there is otherwise not always a clear notion of an underlying object of the placeholder object, because for general $\mathcal{T}$ it is not clear what the underlying object of a finite-product preserving functor $\mathcal{T}\to\mathsf{Set}$ is.

For algebraic examples, I think the assumption above is a rather good categorical explanation why some algebraic structures do or don't have hom-objects with the same structure (induced from the structure on the codomain). The problem is that I don't know how to connect it to Banach spaces.

There is as Sergey Guminov noted above also a link to internal homs, but I can see no general way of knowing that the structure on the internal hom is induced from the codomain in the sense which you describe in your question. If anyone knows of a criterion on a closed monoidal category that ensures this, I am interested.

As I said earlier, I don't know how to connect the Lawvere theory style approach to Banach spaces. There are somewhat categorical descriptions of Banach spaces in terms of enriched categories admitting monoidal functors to the poset $([0,\infty)],\geq)$ with monoidal structure given by addition, but this description is not similar to a Lawvere theory.